# Flutter - Animation not working with flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I am building a Gmail clone in which I have to implement the account avatar animation in the Gmail app bar. I have implemented the UI and animation successfully but when I connect it with Bloc, the animations are not triggering instead(but works without BLocProvider), it renders like using `setState()`. The BlocProvider does its function but not the animation controller. I tried wrapping the widgets animating with BlocBuilder but the result is similar. Have anyone faced similar problems while using Bloc? Is there any way to merge animations with Bloc? Can anyone explain why it's happening like this?

Widget:

```
class GmailAnim extends StatefulWidget {

  VoidCallback onTapFunc;
  Function swipeFunction;

  GmailAnim({
    required this.onTapFunc,
    required this.swipeFunction
  });

  @override
  _GmailAnimState createState() => _GmailAnimState();
}

class _GmailAnimState extends State<GmailAnim> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  List<CircleAvatar> avatars = [
    CircleAvatar(
      child: Text(
        "R",
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            color: Colors.white
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    ),
    CircleAvatar(
      child: Text(
        "J",
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            color: Colors.white
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    ),
    CircleAvatar(
      child: Text(
        "P",
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          color: Colors.white
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
    ),
  ];

  int index = 0;
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> sizeTween;
  late Animation<double> opacityTween;
  late Animation<Offset> offsetTweenUpward;
  late Animation<Offset> offsetTweenDownward;


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150));

    sizeTween = TweenSequence<double>(
        <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
          TweenSequenceItem(
              tween: Tween(begin: 30, end: 0),
              weight: 50
          ),
          TweenSequenceItem(
              tween: Tween(begin: 0, end: 30),
              weight: 50
          )
        ]
    ).animate(_controller);

    opacityTween = TweenSequence<double>(
        <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
          TweenSequenceItem(
              tween: Tween(begin: 1, end: 0),
              weight: 50
          ),
          TweenSequenceItem(
              tween: Tween(begin: 0, end: 1),
              weight: 50
          )
        ]
    ).animate(_controller);

    offsetTweenUpward = Tween<Offset>(
        begin: const Offset(0,0),
        end: const Offset(0, -1)
    ).animate(_controller);

    offsetTweenDownward = Tween<Offset>(
        begin: const Offset(0,0),
        end: const Offset(0, 1)
    ).animate(_controller);


    _controller.addStatusListener((status) {
      widget.swipeFunction;
      print(status.toString());
      log(status.toString());
      if(status == AnimationStatus.completed){
        _controller.reset();
        index = (index + 1) %
            avatars.length;
      }
    });
  }

  bool isUpward = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final offsetTween = isUpward ? offsetTweenUpward : offsetTweenDownward;

    return BlocBuilder<AccountCubit, AccountDetail>(
      builder: (context, state){
        return GestureDetector(
          child: ClipRRect(
            child: AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _controller,
              builder: (context, child){
                return SlideTransition(
                  position: offsetTween,
                  child: AnimatedScale(
                    scale: opacityTween.value,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 35.0,
                      width: 35.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                          color: avatars[index].backgroundColor
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: avatars[index].child,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          onVerticalDragUpdate: (details){
            log(details.localPosition.direction.toString());
            if(details.localPosition.direction < 0){
              setState(() {
                isUpward = true;
                log(isUpward.toString());

              });
              _controller.forward();
              widget.swipeFunction();
            }else{
              setState(() {
                isUpward = false;
                log(isUpward.toString());
              });
              _controller.forward();
              widget.swipeFunction();
            }
          },
          onTap: widget.onTapFunc,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

}
```

Widget 2:

```
class MailTileWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MailModel account;
  Function changeAppBar;

  MailTileWidget({
    required this.account,
    required this.changeAppBar
  });
  @override
  _MailTileWidgetState createState() => _MailTileWidgetState();
}

class _MailTileWidgetState extends State<MailTileWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

  late AnimationController circleAvatarController;
  late Animation<double> rotationAnim;

  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    circleAvatarController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 450)
    );

    rotationAnim = Tween<double>(
        begin: 0,
        end: 180
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: circleAvatarController, curve: Curves.easeIn));
  }
 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AccountCubit, AccountDetail>(
      builder: (context, state){
        return GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7, horizontal: 8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                color: widget.account.isSelected ? Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2): null
            ),
            height: widget.account.attachedFile.isAttached ? 125 : 85,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: AnimatedBuilder(
                        builder: (context, child){
                          return Transform(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: widget.account.isSelected ? Colors.blueAccent : widget.account.senderInfo.profileColor.withOpacity(0.75),
                              child: TweenAnimationBuilder(
                                tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1),
                                builder: (context, double anim, child){
                                  return rotationAnim.value > 90
                                      ? Opacity(
                                    child: AnimatedScale(
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.check,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                                      scale: rotationAnim.value/180,
                                    ),
                                    opacity: rotationAnim.value/200 ,
                                  )
                                      : Text(
                                      widget.account.senderInfo.senderName[0].toString(),
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 21.0,
                                          color: Colors.white
                                      ));
                                },
                                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                              ),
                            ),
                            transform: Matrix4.identity()
                              ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
                              ..rotateY((rotationAnim.value) / 180 * math.pi),
                          );
                        },
                        animation: circleAvatarController,
                      ),
                      onTap: (){

                       
                        setState(() {
                          widget.account.isSelected = !widget.account.isSelected;
                        });
                        widget.account.isSelected ? circleAvatarController.forward() : circleAvatarController.reverse();
                       // Using my Cubit function here but the animation is 
                    //not triggering with this code
                        isItemSelected();
                      },

                    )
                  ],
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 10.0,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                widget.account.senderInfo.senderName,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16.0,
                                    fontWeight: widget.account.isSeen
                                        ? FontWeight.normal
                                        : FontWeight.bold
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                  "10:00"
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        widget.account.title,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14.5,
                            fontWeight: widget.account.isSeen
                                ? FontWeight.normal
                                : FontWeight.bold
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                                widget.account.content,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              ),
                            ),
                            GestureDetector(
                              child: Container(
                                child: widget.account.starred ? Icon(
                                  Icons.star,
                                  color: Colors.orange[300],
                                ):
                                Icon(
                                    Icons.star_border
                                ),
                              ),
                              onTap: (){
                                setState(() {
                                  widget.account.starred = !widget.account.starred;
                                });
                              },
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      if(widget.account.attachedFile.isAttached) Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 5.0),
                            height: 35.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[400]!),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                fileIcon(widget.account.attachedFile.fileType!),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    widget.account.attachedFile.fileName!,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_){
              return MailDetailRoute(
                account: widget.account,
              );
            }));

          },
        );
      }
    );
  }

  isItemSelected(){
    if(widget.account.isSelected){
      BlocProvider.of<AccountCubit>(context).selected();
    }else{
      BlocProvider.of<AccountCubit>(context).notSelected();
    }
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    circleAvatarController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

I am using this widget(GmailAnim()) in the normalAppBar() :

```
class MailRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  _MailRouteState createState() => _MailRouteState();
}

class _MailRouteState extends State<MailRoute> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

  bool starred = false;
  late AnimationController controller;
  late Animation colorAnim;
  late ScrollController _scrollController;
  bool isExtended = false;
  double fabWidth = 52;
  late double startOffset;
  int riveAnimVal1 = 1;
  int riveAnimVal2 = 1;
  bool isFront = true;
  static List<MailModel> presentAccount = account1_mail_data;
  bool onSearchTap = false;
  bool mailSelected = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1, milliseconds: 900)
    );

    colorAnim = ColorTween(
      begin: Colors.green,
      end: Colors.red
    ).animate(controller);

    controller.addStatusListener((status) {

      log("circle Avatar animatinggg");
      if(status == AnimationStatus.completed){
        controller.reset();
      }
    });

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if(_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward){
          setState(() {
              isExtended = true;
              fabWidth = 145;
          });
      }
      if(_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse){
        setState(() {
          isExtended = false;
          fabWidth = 52;
        });
      }
    });

  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: controller,
      builder: (context, child){
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: BlocBuilder<AccountCubit, AccountDetail>(
                builder: (context, state){

                  log(state.toString());
                  return RefreshIndicator(
                    displacement: 65.0,
                    onRefresh: onRefresh,
                    color: colorAnim.value,
                    child: CustomScrollView(
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      slivers: [
                        SliverStack(
                          insetOnOverlap: true,
                          children: [
                            SliverPadding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 75),
                              sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                                  child: _buildItemTitle(titleName: "PRIMARY")
                              ),
                            ),
                            displayContent(state: state),
                            showAppBar(state: state)
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );

                }
            ),
            floatingActionButton: AnimatedContainer(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              width: fabWidth,
              height: 52.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: const [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black38,
                      blurRadius: 4.0,
                      offset: Offset(
                          0, 3
                      )
                    )
                  ]
              ),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
                child: isExtended
                    ? Material(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: (){
                          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ComposeRoute()));
                        },
                        child: Stack(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          children: const [
                            Positioned(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.edit_outlined,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                              left: 15.0,
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              left: 50.0,
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Compose",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      fontSize: 16.0
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                        ),
                        highlightColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.15),
                      ),
                ): Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                  child: InkWell(
                    highlightColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.15),
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ComposeRoute()));
                    },
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.edit_outlined,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )

        );
      }
    );
  }

  Widget showAppBar({required AccountDetail state}){
    if(state is AccountSelected){
      return selectedAppBar(state.numOfItems.toString());
    }else{
      return normalAppBar();
    }
  }

  Widget _buildItemTitle({
    required String titleName,
  }){
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 15.0),
      child: Text(
        titleName,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontSize: 12.0,
            color: Colors.black54,
          letterSpacing: 3.0
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> onRefresh(){
    controller.forward();
    return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  showDialogBox(){
    final alertBox =  popupDialogBox(context);

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context){
        return alertBox;
      }
    );
  }

  Widget popupBottom({required IconData data, required String itemName}){
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        height: 20.0,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(
                data
            ),
            Text(
              itemName,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

   changeAccount(){
    BlocProvider.of<AccountCubit>(context).changeAccount();
  }


  changeAppBar(){
    setState(() {
      mailSelected = false;
    });
  }

  Widget displayContent({required AccountDetail state}){
    if(state is InitialAccount){
      return listBuilderWidget(state.account);
    }else if(state is StarredAccount){
      return listBuilderWidget(state.starredAccount);
    } else if(state is AccountSelected){
      return listBuilderWidget(state.account);
    }else if(state is NoAccountSelected){
      return listBuilderWidget(state.account);
    }else if(state is AccountChanged){
      return listBuilderWidget(state.account);
    }else{
      return SliverPositioned(
        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
  }

  Widget listBuilderWidget(List<MailModel> listAccount){
    return SliverPadding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 110.0),
      sliver : SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index){
              final account = listAccount[index];
              return MailList(
                key: UniqueKey(),
                index: index,
                account: account,
                changeAppBar: changeAppBar,
              );
            },
            childCount: account1_mail_data.length
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget normalAppBar(){
    return SliverPadding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 10.0,
            horizontal: 15.0
        ),
        sliver: SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight: onSearchTap ? 200.0 : 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          pinned: false,
          floating: true,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)
          ),
          shadowColor: Colors.grey,
          elevation: 0.5,
          forceElevated: true,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.grey[300]!
                )
            ),
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        const Icon(
                            Icons.menu
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 10.0,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            height: double.infinity,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: "searchfield",
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Text(
                                  "Search in emails",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      color: Colors.grey[500],
                                      fontSize: 17.0,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.clip
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  GmailAnim(
                    onTapFunc: showDialogBox,
                    swipeFunction: changeAccount,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              onTap: (){
                log("tapped serach");
              },
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }

  Widget selectedAppBar(String numOfItems){
    return SliverAppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      title: Text(
        numOfItems,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black
        ),
      ),
      leading: const Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      actions: [
       
        Icon(
          Icons.delete_outline,
          color: Colors.black54,
          size: 25.0,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 15.0,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.mail_outline,
          color: Colors.black54,
          size: 25.0,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 15.0,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.more_vert,
          color: Colors.black54,
          size: 25.0,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 15.0,
        )
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

Cubit:

```
class AccountCubit extends Cubit<AccountDetail>{

  List<MailModel> account1;
  List<MailModel> account2;
  List<MailModel> account3;

  AccountCubit({
    required this.account1,
    required this.account2,
    required this.account3,
  }):super(InitialAccount(account: account1));

  selected(){
    int i = 1;
    emit(AccountSelected(account: account1, numOfItems: i));
    i++;
  }

  notSelected(){
    emit(NoAccountSelected(account: account1));
  }

  changeAccount(){
    log("Account changeddd");
    emit(AccountLoading());
    emit(AccountChanged(account: account2));
  }

  starredAccount(){
    log("starred Account");
    List<MailModel> starredAccount = [];
    account1.map((e){
      if(e.starred) starredAccount.add(e);
    });
    emit(StarredAccount(starredAccount: starredAccount));
  }

}
```

State:

```
class AccountDetail{

}

class InitialAccount extends AccountDetail{

  List<MailModel> account;

  InitialAccount({required this.account});
}

class AccountSelected extends AccountDetail{

  List<MailModel> account;
  int numOfItems;

  AccountSelected({
    required this.account,
    required this.numOfItems
  });
}

class NoAccountSelected extends AccountDetail{
  List<MailModel> account;

  NoAccountSelected({
    required this.account
  });
}

class AccountChanged extends AccountDetail{

  List<MailModel> account;

  AccountChanged({
    required this.account
  });
}

class AccountLoading extends AccountDetail{

}

class StarredAccount extends AccountDetail{
  List<MailModel> starredAccount;

  StarredAccount({required this.starredAccount});
}
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: @Draško yes but not completely, I separated every widget so that every aspect of UI could hold its own state. But I could add certain chain functions that could work on all. At last, it was a "UI" clone instead of an actual clone

Comment: @Draško Hey, I found a youtube video that might summarise what you have to do [link](https://youtu.be/IOyq-eTRhvo)